Getting errors after installing SSL Certificate in virtualhost and restarting apache service
I've done a certificate signing request using openssl and rekeyed it in Godaddy. I downloaded the SSL certificate zip file and installed it in my Apache server. I ran the apachectl configtest command and it says Syntax OK, but every time I restart Apache I'm getting those errors.


Welcome to AskUbuntu! It looks like there is another process that is already using port 443. Is your server running other services other than Apache to serve data?
